# How to pull the master branch from bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I messed up my local master branch, so I had to delete it. However, I tired to pull it down, but it did not work. I tried `git fetch origin master`, then `git checkout master`. It gave me this error `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.` However, I think I fetch correctly because I got this message

```
From https://url
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Does anyone know how to fetch down the master branch from bitbucket ?

Comment: Refer to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide
It is the most comprehensive guide on the internet. You don't need to look else where

Comment: you can just delete local repo and clone it from bitbusket

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue on my computer with the lastest version of git. 
I deleted my local `master` branch, then do `git fetch && git checkout master` again, it works fine.

In your case, if you're using a "old" version of Git, then try the equivalent checkout to `git checkout <branch>`:

```
git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
```

(you run: `git checkout -b master --track origin/master`)